# Arch Linux: Any keyboard press opens right click context menu

Tags: keyboard, arch-linux, touchpad

Maybe due to recent upgrade, or some screwed up configuration, my Arch install has become unusable. Some time after booting up, mouse stops working, any keyboard key opens the right click context menu, it becomes impossible for me to type anything.

I have removed LXDE, and installed GNOME. This does not solve the problem.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a hardware problem?

Comment: how to check if it's a hardware problem? my touchpad click also stops working,

Comment: Can you boot an other OS and check? I was thinking about that because one time I had this kind of behavior, and it turned out that I forgot that I had a second mouse plugged in, and a book was pressing it's right button permanently. So maybe you have a problem with your keyboard/touchpad, which has nothing to do with your software pb...

Comment: I have disconnected the use mouse, and m at office, not sure if any of the keys are staying pressed down. I've spent all day trying fix this. Feeling completely clueless now. F1!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing this [known issue](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Touchpad_synchronization_issues).

I was forced to (re)try Openbox window manager, and I am pleased that I have had no *Context Menu* craziness since. As long as you've switched your graphical environment once, try that if you are up to it.

If not, examine/post your `/var/log/messages.log` here.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer zero2cx, I have had to spend entire day trying to find a fix. I got to try gnome3, which looked seriously awesome but painfully slow! :( I could not wait to find ways to speed it up. I have wrapped my arch with XFCE4 now, needless to say I'm more than pleased. Will dig the messages.log to see if I find anything fishy.